# Unknown error, no message, CF template is just logically not working for my automatic s3 bucket testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

my template is :

```
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3

          s3 = boto3.client('s3')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            # Get bucket name from the S3 event
            print(event)

            bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

            # Create a bucket policy
            bucket_policy =json.dumps({
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        AES256
                        "aws:kms"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:*",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                      "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                      }
                  }
                } ] })


            # Set the new policy
            s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy),
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::role'
      Runtime: python3.7
  EventRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - CreateBucket
```

This successfully creates a lambda function as well as an event bridge event, i had to manually add the trigger for the eventbridge, and yet when i create an s3 bucket, there is no policy. theres no error references for me to see, and i can not find any logical errors at the moment. This is on a stack i created with the template from above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to investigate this is going to be through CloudWatch.

Firstly check your CloudWatch logs in the region that the Lambda exists. This will identify any issues with the Lambda function such as:

- IAM missing permission for your role
- Python parsing error (invalid syntax)

If there are no logs check CloudWatch metrics to make sure the function it is being invoked. If it is not then, the event is not triggering.

Additionally to have the Lambda added automatically as a trigger you will need to include it as a [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html#cfn-events-rule-targets) of the CloudWatch event rule in the template.

The below is roughly the template you would need.

```
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3

          s3 = boto3.client('s3')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            # Get bucket name from the S3 event
            print(event)

            bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']

            # Create a bucket policy
            bucket_policy =json.dumps({
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                      "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        AES256
                        "aws:kms"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                  "Effect": "Deny",
                  "Principal": "*",
                  "Action": "s3:*",
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                      "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                      }
                  }
                } ] })


            # Set the new policy
            s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy),
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::role'
      Runtime: python3.7
  EventRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - CreateBucket
      Targets:
        - 
          Arn: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
          Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
  PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: "LambdaFunction"
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRule.Arn
```